# Set Page Layout Based on Left or Right Page

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-publisher

Is there any way to create slightly different page layouts for pages that are on the Left of a booklet, vs pages on the Right?

In a magazine that I'm formatting, I'd like for a textbox to be in the upper left corner if it is a Left page, and the upper right corner if it is a Right page.  Naturally, this is a bit of a pain to do manually.

Anyone know of an easy way to do this?  I don't mind having duplicate text boxes (one on both sides), as long as only one is visible at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Create two master pages and apply one to the left and one to the right page. Or, create a two-page master page.

To create two master pages, in Publisher 2007, when you're in your booklet, follow these steps:

1. **Format > Apply Master Page...**
2. Click the link at the bottom of the panel to **View master pages**
3. Click the button at the bottom of the panel for **New Master Page...**
4. The two master pages appear in the left panel.
5. Edit your two master pages to include the elements you want on each side.
6. In the left panel, deselect the check box **Use the same master page for both facing pages**, then choose the master to apply to each page.

If your booklet's pages are not yet filled and what you really want is to populate them with text boxes rather than have an element repeat, you may be better off using a single master page that covers a two-page spread but has a difference between the left and right.

When you create the master page, move the guides at the edge of the page where you want the text box to be, on the left and right pages. Then, use **Insert > Page** to add more pages at the end of the booklet. Be sure to click the option **create one text box on each page** and the new text boxes will align to the guides.